# Assign divs the same height (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs, that should have the same `height`, if the screen size is above a certain width.

I thought its a good idea to use a class `.sameheight` as selector to create a "global working function". Next I would assign another class, to pair the divs, that should have the same height, like so:

```
.sameheight-01
.sameheight-01
.sameheight-02
.sameheight-02  
.sameheight-02
```

I have several issues, that prevent me from writing my own script, as I have not enough skills in javascript/jQuery:

> How can I make it a responsive function, not just set the height once after loading (using window.resize)?
>
> How can I target .sameheight and search for other classes, without writing the same line multiple times (.hasClass(sameheight-01).hasClass(sameheight-02), etc.)?
>
> How can I make this scalable? (Imagen I have twenty groups with ten different media queries)

I have created a [**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/8/) to illustrate my problem.

Comment: To answer your second question: If your classes are "sameheight-XX" you could use a wildcard like:
`$('[class*="sameheight"]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How far back do you have to support?
Because this could be solved using display:flex;

```
.row-sameheight {
   display: flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -moz-box;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/14/)

Comment: Thats a great idea! As its only a visual thing with less priority this is a good to go solution! Can I somehow adopt this even if the div using background-color is nested? (FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/15/ )

Comment: Since the classes are only for background color now just keep them like this
http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/16/

Answer (score 0):

this you could achieve using CSS itself

```
@media (min-width:500px){
    .sameheight {
        min-height:100px;
    }
}
```

or

if u want to do through js/jq, refer the modification of fiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/11/ or 
http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/17/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a scalable version, and (as far as I know (except setting display mode to table cell)) there is no css solution achieving this!

Comment: oh, for this case you could use table 2 column lay out and use media query to display in single column for lower width. 
( or )
use script to set max-height of adjacent cells refer http://jsfiddle.net/qj3ntsjs/17/

Comment: @Manivannan I think that you should be using `.outerHeight()` instead if you were to use a JS solution.